# Do layer.render(in context:) only, when there is something to render

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, uigraphicscontext

Inspired by [tutsline](https://tutsline.wordpress.com/2017/08/14/how-to-create-a-magnifier-effect-in-swift-3-ios/) I've implemented my own Swift 4 magnifier-view class to fit our needs, which is working pretty well excepting two use-cases.

We're using the magnifier to magnify contents of an UIImageView.

1. The magnifier shows black content, when the touch starts in an area of the `UIImageView`, where no image is contained in

[image]

2. When the touch leaves the area, where an image was, the magnifier repeat displaying the last visible content

[image]

The code of the `draw(_ rect:)` method looks like:

```
    // Called by the didSet of touchPoint and the ios view lifecylce
    override public func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        super.draw(rect)

        guard let magnifyingView = viewToMagnify else { fatalError("class WWMagnifierView seems to be used without having set a view to magnify.") }

        if touchPoint != CGPoint.zero {

            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

            context!.translateBy(x: 1 * (self.frame.size.width * 0.5), y: 1 * (self.frame.size.height * 0.5))
            context!.scaleBy(x: 1.5, y: 1.5) // 1.5 is the zoom scale
            context!.translateBy(x: -1 * (touchPoint.x), y: -1 * (touchPoint.y))

            magnifyingView.layer.render(in: context!)
        }
    }
```

Could someone explain me, how to avoid rendering 'no content' in the context? Is there a way to check whether there is renderable content?

This is an image of how it looks like, when the touch location is on content which could be rendered:

[image]

**EDIT:** Because Tobi wanted to know how i use the MagnifierView...

```
// Setup getting called in viewDidAppear to ensure the magnifier works also, when the view appears again on stack.
func setupMagnifier() {

    guard let imageView = imageView else { return }

    if magnifier == nil {

        magnifier = WWMagnifierView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 130, width: 120, height: 120))

        self.view.addSubview(magnifier!)
    }

    magnifier?.viewToMagnify = imageView
}

// Gets triggered from the touch events
func updateMagnifier(for touchLocation: CGPoint) {

    // Update the magnifiers content based on the touch location
    magnifier?.touchPoint = touchLocation
}
```

Setting `touchPoint` here triggers a didSet closure then...

```
public var touchPoint = CGPoint.zero {

    didSet {

        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you using it, can you explain more in code please

Comment: how are you getting the viewToMagnify and what is it

Comment: @Tobi as mentioned above, it is an UIImage which get passed into it when a Touch-Session starts. A mentioned, too, the magnifier works pretty well excepting the both edge-cases, where the magnifier get's no renderable content from the imageview because of the aspect fit scaling.

Comment: @Tobi Updated my question including the code that creates and updates the magnifier view

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem today and what I noticed was it repeats the previous content, The solution was to clear the context before layer.render

```
context.clear(rect)
```